# establishing an optimal take profit

Tags: optimization

Please let me know what you thoughts are on this.
Say for example that you have a perpetuity, which guarantees you indefinite payments of a certain amount. Say then that you also have the opportunity to reinvest all your earnings by buying an even larger perpetuity that will then guarantee even larger payments indefinitely. Provided that the only costs you have would be transaction fees and spread charged by some broker, at what gain level would you close your position in the first perpetuity to establish the position in the new one?

Comment: As soon as gain is above cost.

Comment: so you are saying that as soon as you are in the green say 1 dollar you would close the position and open a new one to infinity?

Comment: Counter question. Why not?